# Why does user.identity.name can't be called in Model - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

As `User.Identity.Name` can be call in View and Controller.

Why does `User.Identity.Name` can't be called in Model even thought my model has a `using System.Web.MVC` library?

Anyone please explain this to me?

Comment: Because `User` is a property of `Controller` and is populated by the current HTTP request.

Comment: Is there a way that it could be called in `Model` somehow?

Comment: What is it that your trying to do? And how do you want to use the value?

Comment: What is it that your trying to do? And how do you want to use the value?

Comment: Well I actually have a method in my Model where it can be in Controller with a parameter. So instead of passing a parameter from controller to model. I'll just have to call it directly to the model.

Comment: Don't do that - pass the value to the model if your model needs it.

Comment: Ok. I will not. But may I know why?

Comment: Because your model knows nothing about the current HttpContext unless you pass the information to the model.